# USB peripheral not responding to SETUP packets

Tags: usb, fpga, protocol, usb-host

I'm writing some Verilog on a Spartan S7-50 FPGA to control a MAX3421E ([datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX3421E.pdf)) over SPI. I've gotten everything working with setting up the chip (full-duplex, Vbus, connection detection, host mode) and now I'm trying to send USB packets to a peripheral (a MIDI keyboard that has an STM32F070RB). But I'm getting a "device timed out error" or "J-state error" when I send over my first SETUP packet, so I'm wondering if I've understood the order of operations correctly since this is my first time working with USB.

I *think* the bare minimum to communicate with this keyboard is to send a SET_ADDRESS and SET_CONFIGURATION control transfer. This was my plan:

1. Wait a bit after chip setup
2. Send SET_ADDRESS setup + HS-IN packets
3. Send SET_CONFIGURATION setup + HS-IN packets
4. Periodically send BULK-IN packets for MIDI data

Is this correct or is there additional setup/control transfers before I can send the SET_ADDRESS? All this is my guessing from a WireShark capture:

[image]

I understand that the SET_ADDRESS isn't shown because it's a device driver level packet. And the other packets are just GET_DESCRIPTOR requests, which I assumed (maybe incorrectly) I could ignore if I know the peripheral I'm working with.

I wait around 15ms after setting up my chip to start a CONTROL transfer (this is arbitrary but I experimented with lots of different times to no avail, I'm not handling SOF anything...). The SETUP packet is:

```
0x00 0x05 0x0100 0x0000 0x0000
                        ^ Length
                 ^ Index
          ^ Peripheral address of 1 (in upper byte)
     ^ SET_ADDRESS
^ bmRequestType
```

which is sent to endpoint 0. Am I correct that this sets the peripheral address to 1? The chip expects bytes on the line MSB first, so I flip `0x01 0x00` to become `0x80 0x00`.

Finally, what exactly is a J-state error? Does the MAX not see the peripheral on the line, even though I've supplied power to it and initiated a transfer at the correct speed?